# Table-per-type inheritance in EF6 still unuseable slow?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, table-per-type

We have a small base class with four derived classes. The derived classes are quite big (~75 properties each, some of them resulting from ComplexTypes as well).

Still: performance should be ok, at least it is with other inheritance strategies. Is table-per-type still unusable in EF6? Is there any workaround/hack/fix to improve the situation?

Note: Performance is not okay at all, querying a table with one entry only takes about two minutes!

Comment: Another developer where I work is encountering this problem and I'd be interested to know if anyone has any advice / insight on it.

Comment: We've changed our database layout in order to workaround this issue (no table-per-type inheritance anymore). This is very unfortunate, however, we found not workaround.

Comment: This doesn't sound like an EF issue. It should be able to handle very large table queries easily. Could you provide a code example?

Comment: @Ermish It is indeed an EF issue. Microsoft has documented it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/performance/perf-whitepaper#71-inheritance-strategies